# Laravel 5.6 pre-build app on PHP 5.6.*

Tags: php, laravel, php-5.6

Can a Laravel 5.6 `pre-build` application run on `PHP 5.6`? I mean, I have two PC's, assume A and B. I have installed the app and all of its dependencies on A, then I want to copy the app's directory to B which have `PHP 5.6`.

Will the application run well `PHP 5.6`?

**Info:**
on computer A:

```
PHP Version: 7.2.5
Nginx installed
```

on computer B:

```
PHP Version: 5.6.36
XAMPP v5.6.36 installed
```

Comment: The Laravel 5.6 requirements say `PHP >= 7.1.3` is required. You'll need to install that and set up Apache (or server) to point to the correct application directory.

Comment: Even if I have all the dependencies?

Comment: @Gregorio yes, you need exact php version, at least `PHP 7.1.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel framework required `PHP >= 7.1.3`.

> The Laravel framework has a few system requirements. Of course, all of
>   these requirements are satisfied by the Laravel Homestead virtual
>   machine, so it's highly recommended that you use Homestead as your
>   local Laravel development environment.
>
> However, if you are not using Homestead, you will need to make sure
>   your server meets the following requirements:
>
> - PHP >= 7.1.3

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation)

PHP applications usually can easily be ported from computer A to computer B. As long as you have all the dependencies of your PHP application in both computers.

**Update**

After couple comments back and forward. The version from PHP in computer A is `7.2` and computer B is `5.6`. To answer your question, this will not work because of Laravel required `PHP >= 7.1.3.`

Comment: So the application will run? I have all the dependencies on A, and I want to just copy that app folder to B

Comment: Do you have all the system dependencies in computer B? Such as your server, PHP, any other external libraries? If the answer is yes it will run. PHP is not a compiled language so everything that you have on computer A you need in order to compile in computer B.

Comment: Yes, just a different PHP version, computer A has PHP 7.2, computer B has PHP 5.6

Comment: @Gregorio, the only way to figure out if work is to try out. Try out and good luck.

Comment: Can you update your question with that piece of information? Version of PHP is crucial in a question like this.